# JSON does not show id from DB

Tags: php, json, firebase, curl, firebase-realtime-database

I returned the data from my firebase database in a JSON file with PHP CURL but it doesn't show me the id of the records

my code:

```
<?php
$url="https://******.firebaseio.com/a_info.json";
$ch= curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
$response=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($response);
?>
```

[image: my data base]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Firebase interprets your sequential, numerical keys as array indices, and returns the results as a JSON array.

If you want to prevent Firebase from performing this conversion, make sure your keys aren't sequential numbers, for example by prefixing them with a short fixed string:

```
"a_info": {
  "key0": {...},
  "key1": {...},
  ...
}
}
```

Also see: [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).